# How to pass credential binding in environment directive conditionally

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

This doesn't work:

```
environment {
    Pass = "${blah == 'yes' ? credentials('somecred') : credentials('otherCred')}"
```

I can set an env var to `credentials()` directly but when trying to use the ternary statement inside of the string interpolator like above it doesn't pass the actual creds, it passes a stringified object.

Is there a one-liner for doing this in the environment{} directive?

Jenkins lets you sneak the string interpolator into the environment block to evaluate code, is there another Groovy construct I can use here that will work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jenkins pipeline dsl makes me weep

```
# Define outside of pipeline block
def MYENV_VAR = somevar == 'yes' ? 'cred-id-1' : 'cred-id-2'

pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
            MYENV = credentials("${MYENV_VAR}")
```